# I would like to prefix my CakePHP plugins namespace with my name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I have a plugin I am calling AdminLTE, and I have other plugins that rely on AdminLTE, so I would like to prefix all my AdminLTE plugins with AdminLTE

For instance

```
namespace AdminLTE\Calendar\Controller;
```

Where Calendar is the name of the actual plugin

How would I go about extending the CakePHP Autoloader to be able to find a class like below... And if possible, can I create that autoloader in a plugin?

```
namespace AdminLTE\Calendar\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I go about extending the CakePHP Autoloader...

Something like this in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "AdminLTE\\Calendar\\": "plugins/Calendar/src/",
        "AdminLTE\\": "plugins/AdminLTE/src/"
    }
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths

> And if possible, can I create that autoloader in a plugin?

If your plugins have composer.json then it should be possible.